# Alternative to update large tables in a database

Tags: .net, sql-server, database

I have table in a SQL Server database which is ~5000 rows. Since there are changes every day, data in this table has to be updated every day which can include anything from adding/deleting/modifying the columns.

Currently I have written a batch job that runs twice a day which "updates" the columns (deletes all rows in table then adds new data again). Data is mostly collected through REST API calls to Azure DevOps.

My question is there any alternative so data update can occur faster for the table?

The latest data I can only get through API calls to Azure DevOps only

Comment: you can try to use SqlBulkCopy its a library for bulk changes

also why are you deleting all of the rows ? cannot you just fetch the data that has been changed in any way and run the update only on this rows ?

Comment: Sounds like you might want a `MERGE` but it's not clear. Do all rows have to change every day?

Comment: @jakubpodhaisky as far as I am aware SqlBulkCopy means converting my data to DataTable format which then directly writes to server. Isn't that just a replacement of a multiple INSERT INTO lines?

Comment: @Charlieface no an estimated guess i would say around 10-20 new rows will be added per day, 3-5 deletions, but modifications to existing ones will be hundreds every day easily

Comment: @MuditBalooja The best I can give you is how we do it in our company 
We use SqlBulkCopy to create a query and we have a separate program that checks what rows were changed|added|deleted and query only those affected we run it twice a day

Comment: @MuditBalooja I guess there is a reason why we use this aproach I cannot help you than 
Hope you come to an alternative

Comment: SqlBulkCopy is most appropriate for a large number of rows. 5K rows is small. I would expect even normal inserts to take no more than a few seconds to insert 5K rows. If you are experiencing performance issues, are you sure it's the inserts rather than the REST API?

Comment: @jakubpodhaisky I understand but the table I have is more like record keeping, no one is changing the table, i am just adding stuff about the existing pipelines like name, project, latest build etc
Thank you for advise will definitely look into SqlBulkCopy More

Comment: @DanGuzman issue isnt the sql querying it is the rest api call, was looking to find a way to make calls to only those projects which were recently changed

Comment: @DanGuzman I believe TVPs outpeform multi-value `INSERT` after tens of rows, and BulkCopy/bcp/BULK INSERT outperform TVPs at around 1000 rows. That's what I've seen myself and read.

Comment: So why don't you just use `UPDATE` or `MERGE` to just modify the rows you need, why dump the whole table and start again?

Comment: @Charlieface, agreed there's a tipping point for inserts/TVPs/SqlBulCopy. My point is full daily refresh should take only a few seconds so performance should be a non-issue regardless of the method. It seems the actual issue here is how to optimize the rest API call to extract only changed data.

Comment: @DanGuzman yeah we do twice a day refresh the recent changes refresh around 100K of rows takes around 3 minutes usually So Iam pretty sure the problem does not lie in the quering the database and refresh itself

Comment: @Charlieface because UPDATE only works in the case of modifications which means I need to identify first which lines were modified which means making 1000s of api call to get latest data, then compare, then update. Thought it would be easier to just dump and insert

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You either need to have a `modifiedSince` parameter on the Rest API, or you can get all of it (maybe a CSV or other bulk download?) and dump it into a temp table or table variable, and then do a joined `UPDATE`. If your API doesn't have either of those options then you need to speak to whoever created it. That's not a SQL issue.

Comment: @Charlieface Currently I am using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi and similar packages in my C# application to get the data; overall it takes around 17-20 minutes to extract all of my data (doesnt include inserting to database). Also will look into using UPDATE instead of INSERT/DELETE see if it improves performance, Thanks!

Comment: OK so this whole mention of SQL is a complete red herring. You need to look at the API and work out why its taking so long. Normally there is a GET endpoint to list everything, or everything modified since a date. If thats not available then speak to whoever created the API. I suggest you delete this question as it's a complete irrelevance to your actual problem.

Comment: First of all 5000 records for SQL Server are peanuts. If you need to empty the whole table go for a truncate and a bulk insert. If you need an example with proven documentation I am willing to craft a more exhaustive response